# What is wrong with this .htaccess? Worked fine before, but not now

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I had this working on an old server and unfortunately had to switch over to a new one which had to be remade from the ground up, and now this .htaccess is not working, it throws Error 500 to any request in its directory.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+admin\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ admin.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

<Files .htaccess>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>

<Files global.php>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>

Options All -Indexes
```

The goal is to send requests to `www.domain.tld/directory/log` to `www.domain.tld/directory/admin.php?page=log` 
and to also prevent viewing of the `.htaccess` file itself or the file `global.php`
As a side note I did try writing it directly into `apache2.conf` as a directory setting however this caused the apache2 service to be unable to start.

Answer (score 0):

To know what is the problem exactly, you have to check apache error_log file

for cPanel Servers, you can try this command:

```
tail /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log
```

now the most popular 500 error for .htaccess is the use of `Options` line

many servers configs don't allow execution of `Options` in .htaccess for security reasons (overwrite configs, enable Perl execution... etc)

most server too have `Options -MultiViews` and `Options All -Indexes` already,
comment `Options` lines with `#` and your website should works just fine.

Comment: Commented both lines out and no change. Error log said this: `htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
`

Comment: Most likely this is it: _defined by a module not included in the server configuration_ – so go check with your server admin, if the mod_rewrite module is available (and if you are allowed to use it.)

Comment: Ran `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and it is working now, thanks for the answer.